# Run Specific Stages on Schedule via YML

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure Devops YML Multi-stage pipeline:

Is it possible to run a specific stage on a schedule without manual input to the pipeline to specify the stage?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do, is use a condition on the stages of your yaml build. You can use the "Build.Reason" variable (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to determine whether or not a stage should run:

```
stages:
- stage: Stage1
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
  jobs:
  - some jobs
- stage: Stage2
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
  jobs:
  - some jobs
```

The above example runs only stage1 when the build was triggered from a schedule, and only stage2 if the build was not triggered from a schedule. You can of course adjust the conditions to your need.

Another option is to move the stages to templates, and then create 2 separate yaml pipelines using the template files containing the correct stages. This way you only need to define the contents of a stage once, but you can re-use it in several pipelines. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops

Comment: awesome thank you, that should help towards my goal :)

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule a stage's run-window by creating a "check" for the stage's environment.

*If you have an environment already, skip to step 4.

1. in ADO, mouse over the `Pipelines` icon and click `Environments`
2. click the `New Environment` button at the top.
3. give it a name that your scheduled stage will use and click  `Create`
4. click the `3 dots` next to the "Add resource" button and select `Approvals and Checks`
5. click the `plus` button and choose `Business Hours`
6. schedule the stage run then click `Create`
7. make sure to add the environment name you created to the first job in the stage you're scheduling for.

Answer (score -1):

Just expanding on the above answer. Since variables definition is after the schedule triggers, would have define the schedule as a variable and then set a conditional statement when the build is triggered based on a schedule and equal to schedule1 variable then run the schedule 1... stage 1... and similar applies to schedule2 which runs the stage2. Only downfall is that you would need to define cron schedule twice.

```
 schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
    exclude:
    - releases/old/*

- cron: "0 */6 * * *"
  displayName: Every 6 hours build
  branches:
    include:
    - releases/*
  always: true

variables:
  stage1schedule1 = "0 0 * * *"
  stage2schedule2 = "0 */6 * * *"


stages:
- stage: Stage1
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.stage1schedule1, "0 0 * * *"), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
  jobs:
  - schedule1 jobs
- stage: Stage2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.stage2schedule2, "0 */6 * * *"), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
  jobs:
  - schedule2 jobs
```